# Is there any way to choose how many features are selected in Binary Particle Swarm Optimization?

Tags: python, feature-selection, particle-swarm

I implemented BPSO as a feature selection approach using the pyswarms library. [I followed this tutorial.](https://pyswarms.readthedocs.io/en/development/examples/feature_subset_selection.html)

Is there a way to limit the maximum number of features? If not, are there other particle swarm (or genetic/simulated annealing) python-implementations that have this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way is to introduce a penalty for using any number of features. The in the following code a objective i defined

```
    # Perform classification and store performance in P
    classifier.fit(X_subset, y)
    P = (classifier.predict(X_subset) == y).mean()
    # Compute for the objective function
    j = (alpha * (1.0 - P)
        + (1.0 - alpha) * (1 - (X_subset.shape[1] / total_features)))

    return j
```

What you could do, is add a penalty if the number of features is about `max_num_features`, e.g.

```
features_count = np.count_nonzero(m)
features_overflow = np.clip( max_num_features - features_count, 0, 10)

feature_overflow_penalty = (features_overflow / 10)
```

and define a new objective with:

```
j = (alpha * (1.0 - P)
        + (1.0 - alpha) * (1 - (X_subset.shape[1] / total_features))) - feature_overflow_penalty
```

This is not tested, and there is work to do to find the right penalty. A alternative is to never suggest/try features above certain threshold.